# Discord.py Add Role to member

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on discord.py bot that'll be used to manage licenses on discord server.
Currently stuck on how to add role after successful redeem of code.
I added 3 roles in my discord server(1Day, 7Days, 30Days),
how do I make bot to add role to user who successfully redeemed the license?

Here's my code for now:

```
import discord
import random
import re
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()


l1d = open('licenses1d', 'r').read().splitlines()
l7d = open('licenses7d', 'r').read().splitlines()
l30d = open('licenses30d', 'r').read().splitlines()

def license_gen1d():
    a = 'qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890'
    license = ''

    while True:
        while len(license) < 30:
            character = random.choice(a)
            license += character
        if len(license) == 30:
            with open('licenses1d', 'a') as f:
                f.writelines(license + '\n')
                f.close()
            print('Successfuly Generated 1 day License: ' + license)
            return(license)

def license_gen7d():
    a = 'qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890'
    license = ''

    while True:
        while len(license) < 30:
            character = random.choice(a)
            license += character
        if len(license) == 30:
            with open('licenses7d', 'a') as f:
                f.write(license + '\n')
                f.close()
            print('Successfuly Generated 7 days License: ' + license)
            return(license)

def license_gen30d():
    a = 'qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890'
    license = ''

    while True:
        while len(license) < 30:
            character = random.choice(a)
            license += character
        if len(license) == 30:
            with open('licenses30d', 'a') as f:
                f.write(license + '\n')
                f.close()
            print('Successfuly Generated 30 days License: ' + license)
            return(license)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$test'):
        await message.channel.send('test!')

    if message.content.startswith('$generate 1d'):
        await message.channel.send('Generating license for 1 day')
        license = license_gen1d()
        await message.channel.send(license)
    
    if message.content.startswith('$generate 7d'):
        await message.channel.send('Generating license for 7 days')
        license = license_gen7d()
        await message.channel.send(license)

    if message.content.startswith('$generate 30d'):
        await message.channel.send('Generating license for 30 days')
        license = license_gen30d()
        await message.channel.send(license)

    if message.content.startswith('$redeem'):
        rcode = re.findall('redeem (.*)', message.content)[0]
        if rcode in l1d:
            await message.channel.send('Successfully Redeemed Code for 1 day use!')
        elif rcode in l7d:
            await message.channel.send('Successfully Redeemed Code for 7 day use!')
        elif rcode in l30d:
            await message.channel.send('Successfully Redeemed Code for 30 day use!')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Invalid code!')







client.run('token')
```

Comment: I'm unsure how to help you with this topic, but I couldn't help but notice that you declared `a` multiple times with the same value. Just make it a global variable.

Comment: Also I recommend using commands for the actions and not checking every message.  It makes it much easier to create aliases, and role checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
member = message.author
role = get(message.guild.roles, name = "test role")
await member.add_roles(role, atomic=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding and editing roles to a user,

```
member = message.author #gets the member to edit
var = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = "role name")
# This will get the role you want to edit^
member.add_role(var) # adds the role
await var.edit(color=0x008000, reason="The reason")
#and edits the color
```

For more parameters you can edit visit https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role
If this works don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I had to change a code a little tho.
Here's what I came up with:

            member = message.author
            role = get(message.guild.roles, name = "test role")
            await member.add_roles(role, atomic=True)

Comment: All good was just a base for you to build on

Answer (score 1):

If the license key is correct you get the author of the message, then update their roles. with a function of `Member.roles`. I think the documentation has an example of it (with code) if you search it up. I am not able to open the docs right now and I don't remember the exact command name and parameters.